# Can someone illustrate the procedure of python name mangling?

Tags: python

The [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions) says

> Private name mangling: When an identifier that textually occurs in a class definition begins with two or more underscore characters and does not end in two or more underscores, it is considered a private name of that class. Private names are transformed to a longer form before code is **generated** for them.

I am trying to get a better understanding about this procedure of Python code to be generated.

generated by what? the Python interpreter?

generated to what? the byte code?

is this figure apply this procedure?

[image]

can someone illustrate this procedure in more detail?

Comment: Are you asking about name mangling or python code compilation strategy, specifically?

Comment: @DaemonPainter "python code compilation strategy", thanks.

Comment: then, may I suggest to rephrase your question to be more specific? Or open a new one, since this got a really nice answer about name mangling? As you can see, it is prone to misleading interpretation that are of no benefit to you. I'd go with option 2: open a new one and rephrase this to be specific about name mangling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've made me curious, so you've made me look this up. First, when you look at the resulting byte code, it already uses [`STORE_NAME`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dis.html#opcode-STORE_NAME) with the "mangled" name.

Who does it and when then? https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Python/compile.c Holds the answer:

> This file compiles an abstract syntax tree (AST) into Python bytecode.

And the corresponding function would be [`_Py_Mangle`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/c37447481ec8f6d0e49d0587ec0de3f9e7d56b28/Python/compile.c#L225-L290) (*"Name mangling: `__private` becomes `_classname__private`."*)